# cudaTextureObject_t compatibility with Fermi

Tags: cuda

I have implemented a kernel that process data where the input comes from an `cudaTextureObject_t`. To increase the throughput of my method, I call this kernel with *N* different stream objects. Therefore, I create *N* texture objects that are then passed to the different kernel calls.

This works perfectly well on GPUs with Kepler architecture. However, now I want to use this method also on a GPU with Fermi architecture, where no `cudaTextureObject_t` is available.

My question is as follows: Is there a way to make an abstraction based on texture references, or do I have to completely rewrite my code for the older architecture?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to re-write your code. It isn't possible to encapsulate a texture reference inside a class or structure, nor pass a texture reference to a kernel.

Comment: Is it also not possible to pass a `cudaTextureObject_t' (or pointer to this) to a kernel and I have always to use the global variable?